XPATH Not Found through Placeholder or Label
I'm creating a Selenium tool to automatically fill out contact forms on websites. I select the appropriate input/textarea through By.NAME or By.XPATH. For the most part, it is working, but I'm having issues in reliability and I can't figure out what the error in the XPATH is. This is my code:
    try:
    message_name_list = [
        "your-message"
    ]
    message_xpath_list = [
        "//label[contains(.,'Anything else you would like us to know?')]/following-sibling::div[1]/textarea",
        "//textarea/@placeholder[contains, 'Message']"
    ]
    
    for key in message_name_list:
        try:
            select_box_message = driver.find_element(By.NAME, key)
            if select_box_message and driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
                select_box_message.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
            else:
                select_box_message.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                select_box_message.send_keys(Message)
        except:
            print("Message Name Not Found")
            
    for key in message_xpath_list:
        try:
            select_box_message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, key)
            if select_box_message and driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
                select_box_message.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
            else:
                select_box_message.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                select_box_message.send_keys(Message)
        except:
            print("Message XPATH Not Found")
except: 
    print("Message N/A")

I am using a similar try/except statement for other fields, and it is working as intended. However, textarea inputs are causing me some issues.
This is the relevant code for the website in question:
<div>
  <label class="gfield_label gform-field-label" for="input_1_5">Message</label>
  <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_textarea">
    <textarea name="input_5" id="input_1_5" class="textarea large" placeholder="Message" aria-invalid="false" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

I figure I could find it by name ("input_5"), but as this changes between website forms, I feel like that may cause issues down the line.
Thank you for any help!
EDIT:
The If/Else statement was causing the issue. With it omitted, it works. I tried changing it to the code block below, but there is still an issue.
    try:
    message_name_list = [
        "your-message"
    ]
    message_xpath_list = [
        "//label[contains(.,'Anything else you would like us to know?')]/following-sibling::div[1]/textarea",
        "//textarea[1][contains(@placeholder, 'Message')]"
    ]
    for key in message_name_list:
        try:
            select_box_message = driver.find_element(By.NAME, key)
            select_box_message.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
                select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
            else:
                select_box_message.send_keys(Message)
        except:
            print("Message Name Not Found")
            
    for key in message_xpath_list:
        try:
            select_box_message = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, key)
            select_box_message.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
                select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
            else:
                select_box_message.send_keys(Message)
        except:
            print("Message XPATH Not Found")
except: 
    print("Message N/A")


Probably //textarea[contains(@placeholder, 'Message')]

That is my suspicion as well, but I have tried many combinations and still no success.

Try at browser's dev console with $x("//textarea[contains(@placeholder, 'Message')]")

Got somewhere with that. It is returning a valid result as "textarea#input_1_5.textarea.large". I tried adding "large" to the XPATH selector to make "//textarea.large[contains(@placeholder, 'Message')]"

The result shown it's just a label for the found element. textarea.large makes no sense on that xpath

So it turns out that the underlying issue is with the If/Else statement in my code. I just ran it without it and it worked. I changed the If/Else (refer to the original post for code block) to something different, but it's still not working.

Trying to write general code to handle all kinds of forms is generally a bad idea. Can it be done? Yes/Maybe... depending on the complexity of the form and the flows through the form. A better approach would be to create simple methods to handle filling in each form, or a portion of the form if the form is long/complex. Do some reading on page object model and follow it for the forms. Your code will end up being much simpler, easier to read and follow, and easier to debug.
I guarantee you that you will spend much more time trying to make generic code fit all kinds of situations than you will just writing simple code for each form.
But, if you insist... some feedback

Code like
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
    select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
else:
    select_box_message.send_keys(Message)

will never work because if driver.find_element() fails to find the element, you'll immediately get a NoSuchElementException and the script stops before the if can be evaluated.
The better way to do this is to use .find_elements() (plural) and then see if the list is empty, indicating no element was found.
if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
    select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
else:
    select_box_message.send_keys(Message)


Another issue is
select_box_message = driver.find_element(By.NAME, key)
if select_box_message and driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
    select_box_message.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
else:
    select_box_message.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    select_box_message.send_keys(Message)

In cases like this, your if is checking for the existence of select_box_message but you are clicking this element in both the if AND the else branches. What if the absence of select_box_message is why the if failed? Then you are going to fail when you try to click it in the else branch.

Some suggestions:

Don't wrap large blocks of code in try-except. Only exception handle what you are going to specifically handle, not just print messages. Otherwise you hide the issue and it makes debugging much more difficult.

There is a programming concept called DRY, aka Don't Repeat Yourself. The idea is to minimize code repetition.
An example from your code
if ...:
    select_box_message.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
else:
    select_box_message.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    select_box_message.send_keys(Message)

In this case, both the if and the else blocks contain
select_box_message.click()
time.sleep(1)

so move those outside the if-else. This looks like
select_box_message.click()
time.sleep(1)
if ...:
    select_box_message.send_keys(ShortMessage)
else:
    select_box_message.send_keys(Message)

Now you have fewer lines of code, it's easier to read and follow, and easier to debug.



If forced to take this approach, I would simplify things.
Using the concept of DRY, your two code blocks are already exactly the same except for the initial locator type of By.NAME vs By.XPATH. If you pull the locator type out of the method and put it into the input parameter, you can combine your lists of locators AND write a single method to handle both types (and even others), significantly simplifying your code.
Refactored code is below.
def enter_message(locators):
    short_message = ""
    message = ""
    for locator in locators:
        select_box_message = driver.find_element(*locator)
        select_box_message.click()
        if driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']"):
            select_box_message.send_keys(short_message)
        else:
            select_box_message.send_keys(message)

message_locators = [
    (By.NAME, "your-message"),
    (By.XPATH, "//label[contains(.,'Anything else you would like us to know?')]/following-sibling::div[1]/textarea"),
    (By.XPATH, "//textarea/@placeholder[contains, 'Message']")
]

enter_message(message_locators)

